# Is it okay to recommend other Linux distros here?

Tags: discussion

I recently found a question [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4124/3515) and I want to recommend another Linux distro to the asker. Is that okay here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only in very rare cases would the solution be to recommend another distro. There is nothing hard and fast against it, but it would generally be frowned upon unless it was absolutely necessary.